# Prevent svg paths from overflowing

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple SVG image with a line in it:

```
<svg class="icon icon-person" width="25rem" height="25rem" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <style>
    path {
      stroke-width: 5 !important;
    }
  </style>
  <path d="M2.5 0 V 200"></path>
</svg>
```

It draws a simple vertical line along the left border of the SVG image. My `stroke-width` is constant and is equal to `5`.

In order for the `path` not to overflow the SVG image area, I had to set the `path` starting point `x` coordianate to `2.5` which is 50% of its width. However, it feels confusing to mind those overflow every time I draw something near the edge of the SVG image.

So what I thought is to wrap all my paths into some `g` element or something, set its size to `195` x `195` and offset it by `2.5` units from the edge of the SVG image, then specify the position of all paths inside it relative to the `g` element without having to deduct that 50% of the border width.

The problem is that `g` elements cannot be positioned so I am stuck Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: <g> elements can be positioned. Set a translate transform on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `transform` a group 's contents.

```html
<svg class="icon icon-person" width="25rem" height="25rem" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <style>
    path {
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 5 !important;
    }
  </style>
  <g transform="translate(2.5, 0)">
    <path d="M0 0 V 200"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That's actually how I solved the problem. Thanks!